# Trying to get started with Unix on a Windows laptop

Tags: ubuntu, windows, laptop

I caught a cold and my brain hurts just looking at the pc screen but I wanna get started learning Unix asap.

Basically, I've acquired another laptop and I want to install Unix on it so I can try it out and see if I even have a chance at gaining proficiency. I feel like it's mandatory to use if I want to dig deeper into computer systems and programming.

Which state of Unix should I use? Daemon? Ubuntu? How do I get it up and running on a windows laptop? I should be able to find books or tutorials but if you know of any that are better than the rest that would help too.

Comment: You have the choice : http://distrowatch.com/ or http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=major

Answer (score 1):

> Which state of Unix should I use? Daemon? Ubuntu?

*Daemon* isn't a style of unix.  It's a term referring to a [background process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29).

*Ubuntu* isn't quite a style of unix either.  It's a GNU/Linux distribution.  GNU/Linux is a [unix-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_like) operating system.  A [true unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification#Registered_UNIX_systems) is one which is certified according to a standard, although as noted at the bottom of that list, many unix-like systems (including linux) might be so certifiable if it were so desired.

I don't think you want to bother looking into the certified ones for your laptop as they will either be incompatible, expensive, outdated, or some combination of all three.  Have a look into some variant of either **GNU/Linux** or **BSD**.  With regard to the former, *Ubuntu* is a relatively newcomer-friendly distribution; the other big contenders in that category would be *Fedora* and *Debian* (from which Ubuntu is derived), but there are more.

Answer (score 1):

UNIX itself is used mostly in corporate environments, is not free, and has been falling out of favor as of late, for a variety of reasons, such as a lack of hardware compatibility, limited ergonomics and user-friendliness in the command line environment, and other reasons which I am not as familiar with, personally, due to a lack of exposure.

If you really want to get close to a UNIX experience, there are unix-like operating systems available for free, such as Oracle and Solarishttp, FreeBSD, and others.

If you're looking for something a bit easier to get started with, and that is more likely to be compatible with your laptop, GNU/Linux is a good choice.  It has many variants, and depending on what you intend to do with your system, you can probably find the right one for you. Distro Watch has a great [guide to the top 10 most popular GNU/Linux and BSD distrobutions](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=major) that should help make your decision easier.

Once you've selected the perfect operating system, the next step is to research, research, research! The more you understand about your system hardware, about how to partition your disk to dual-boot Windows and your other operating system (assuming you want to), and about the installation and setup of your chosen distro, the smoother the whole experience will be. I highly recommend http://www.linuxquestions.org/ as a great starting point for learning all you can about GNU/Linux. The site contains multiple excellent tutorials, and there are lots of very knowledgeable experts on the forums who are happy to answer any questions.

Once you are ready, download the ISO (disc image) file, burn it to a DVD using your software of choice - search Microsoft's website for a guide on how to do this in Windows 7.

Reboot using your newly-created install disc, and off you go.

Good luck on your adventure into the world beyond Windows! ;)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use **VirtualBox** or **vmware** and install the Linux OS in them. As a relatively new user, you need more freedom to execute the commands and figure out how they actually work. For this purpose, **Virtualbox** or **Vmware** serves as the perfect practice bed. For example,

If you execute,

```
rm -rf \ home
```

**Just see the space before home**. It will delete the entire OS and you have to reinstall the OS again. But with VirtualBox, you can experiment such things in a guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest non-committal way to get started if you're running Windows is to run Linux as a virtual machine.

1. Download and install [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org/).
2. Download a pre-built disk image, such as from [here](http://virtualboximages.com/Free.VirtualBox.VDI.Downloads) or [here](http://virtualboxes.org/images/).
3. Inside VirtualBox, create a virtual machine, specifying the disk image you downloaded earlier.
4. Start the virtual machine!

The initial password is listed alongside the download link for the disk image.  Be sure to change it as soon as possible.

The pre-built images are great for experimentation, since you don't have to go through the normal installation process.  You can speed-date several Linux distributions in a short amount of time.  However, since they are contributed by random Internet users, there is no guarantee for their quality or legitimacy.  For any serious work, you'll want to download the distribution media and install Linux yourself, either as a virtual machine or on the hardware itself.

The flavour of Linux you pick is a matter of opinion.  Ubuntu is a reasonable choice for beginners since it is still quite popular, and you can ask questions about it on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).